# Login page error in abp, showing invalid client id

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, abp

[login_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye8b6.png)

[logonpage_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaTkD.png)

```
error:invalid_request
error_description:The specified 'client_id' is invalid.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052
```

error:invalid_request
error_description:The specified 'client_id' is invalid.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052

Answer (score 1):

It is kinda self explanatory, the **client_id** in the database (openiddict) does not match with the one you provide in your application OpenIdConnect configuration.

Check the dataseeder that seeds the openiddict data. Run the dbmigrator and check the database that your client exist in the database.
Check your application:

- If angular, check the **clientId** under the **oAuthConfig** section in `environment.ts` file.
- If MVC/Blazor, check the **ClientId** under the **AuthServer** section if `appsettings.json` file.

They should be the same with the one in the database (relatively the dataseeder).